# Deleting until whitespace in Sublime Text

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

Is there any way to delete all characters untill first whitespace in Sublime. I know that you can use `ctrl+delete` to do that but it stops at non-word characters(",:,&,*, etc). When you try to delete `aaa aaa 2+a`, from the end, it will delete `2+a` until `+` sign, but it will delete `aaa` until space. I need to change that so it will delete `2+a` until first space. Solution can be anything; changing settings, plug-in.

Comment: You can write a regex, search for it, select all and remove.

Comment: I do that while typing, like when you use `ctrl+backspace`. Just need to delete all no-space characters up to first space/white space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution for this. It's via this plugin:

https://packagecontrol.io/packages/KeyboardNavigation

Key for it is:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+backspace"], "command": "delete_to_beg_of_contig_boundary", "args": {"forward": false} }
```

It deletes any characters right to left until first whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a Sublime Text plugin to delete text as you require. It is almost identical to ST's `delete_word` command but breaks only at whitespace/non-whitespace.

When called the plugin deletes text from the cursor to the next or previous group of characters, the grouping being defined as either whitespace or non-whitespace characters. Thus if run several times in succession it will alternate between deleting groups of whitespace and non-whitespace characters ahead or behind the cursor. The forwards parameter of the `run()` method (i.e. the command's arg) controls the deletion direction.

Save the plugin somewhere in your config `Packages` folder hierarchy. e.g.

```
.../sublime-text-3/Packages/User/DeleteToWhitespace.py
```

Add key bindings to your user `.sublime-keymap` file. e.g.

```json
// 
// These key bindings override the ST 'delete_word' keys but use whatever keys you want.
// You could use `super+delete` and `super+backspace` and keep ST's delete keys intact.
// 
{ "keys": ["ctrl+delete"], "command": "delete_to_whitespace", "args": {"forwards": true} },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+backspace"], "command": "delete_to_whitespace", "args": {"forwards": false} },
```

Below is the `DeleteToWhitespace.py` plugin. It has been uploaded to [this GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/mattst/cdae8ddc0addbb9fd6c99db919f5dbe3) – this links directly to [the raw source code](https://gist.github.com/mattst/cdae8ddc0addbb9fd6c99db919f5dbe3/raw/6ce9a453da607db0d0a26726e6d33c3448dbc550/DeleteToWhitespace.py).

```py
#
# Name:        Delete To Whitespace
# Requires:    Plugin for Sublime Text v3
# Command:     delete_to_whitespace
# Args:        forwards: bool (delete backwards if false)
# License:     MIT License
#

import sublime, sublime_plugin, re

class DeleteToWhitespaceCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    """
    A Sublime Text plugin that deletes text from the cursor to the next or
    previous group of characters, the grouping being defined as either
    whitespace or non-whitespace characters. Thus if run several times in
    succession it will alternate between deleting groups of whitespace and
    non-whitespace ahead or behind the cursor. The forwards parameter of the
    run() method (i.e. the command's arg) controls the deletion direction.
    """

    def run(self, edit, forwards=True):
        self.edit = edit
        self.forwards = forwards

        if forwards:
            self.delete_forwards()
        else:
            self.delete_backwards()

    def delete_forwards(self):
        whitespace_regex = "^\s+"
        non_whitespace_regex = "^\S+"

        for sel in self.view.sel():

            if sel.size() > 0:
                self.view.erase(self.edit, sel)
                continue

            # ∴ sel.a == sel.b == sel.begin() == sel.end()
            # view.full_line() includes the trailing newline (if any).
            cursor = sel.a
            line = self.view.full_line(cursor)
            cursor_to_eol = sublime.Region(cursor, line.end())
            cursor_to_eol_str = self.view.substr(cursor_to_eol)

            match = re.search(whitespace_regex, cursor_to_eol_str)
            if match:
                self.erase_matching_characters(cursor, match)
                continue

            match = re.search(non_whitespace_regex, cursor_to_eol_str)
            if match:
                self.erase_matching_characters(cursor, match)
                continue

    def delete_backwards(self):
        whitespace_regex = "\s+$"
        non_whitespace_regex = "\S+$"

        for sel in self.view.sel():

            if sel.size() > 0:
                self.view.erase(self.edit, sel)
                continue

            # ∴ sel.a == sel.b == sel.begin() == sel.end()
            # view.line() excludes the trailing newline (if any).
            cursor = sel.a
            line = self.view.line(cursor)
            cursor_to_bol = sublime.Region(cursor, line.begin())
            cursor_to_bol_str = self.view.substr(cursor_to_bol)

            # Delete the newline of the 'previous' line.
            if cursor_to_bol.size() == 0 and cursor > 0:
                erase_region = sublime.Region(cursor, cursor - 1)
                self.view.erase(self.edit, erase_region)
                continue

            match = re.search(whitespace_regex, cursor_to_bol_str)
            if match:
                self.erase_matching_characters(cursor, match)
                continue

            match = re.search(non_whitespace_regex, cursor_to_bol_str)
            if match:
                self.erase_matching_characters(cursor, match)
                continue

    def erase_matching_characters(self, cursor, match):
        match_len = match.end() - match.start()
        if self.forwards:
            erase_region = sublime.Region(cursor, cursor + match_len)
        else:
            erase_region = sublime.Region(cursor, cursor - match_len)
        self.view.erase(self.edit, erase_region)
```

Comment: I have tried this and nothing is happening when I press hotkey.